# Is Embedding layer output stochastic?

Tags: keras, embedding

If I use two identical models to learn over a dataset, but the order in which the samples are presented differs, would an embedding layer output the exact embeddings?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will not get exact embeddings. The parameters of embeddings depend on how gradient decent selects them, so you probably get different values when the sample batch order is different. Furthermore, there is an initial random weight initialization for embedding layer, which also could contribute to a difference.

However, I would expect that 2 words close in one embedding will be also close in another embedding.